# Order 2 tables by column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 SQL Server tables that both have hundreds of columns.

A sample of table 1 is:

```
ID    ColA   ColC   ColD  ColF ...
```

A sample of table 2 is:

```
ID    ColB   ColE ...
```

I need to join on column ID but then have the columns print out alphabetical.  For right now I need the names of the columns in alphabetical order. I don't care about the data in each column yet.

So it should be:

```
ID  ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF ...
```

Comment: That doesn't matter and isn't your call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to help build the query:

```
SELECT ',' + name 
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id IN (OBJECT_ID('Table1'),OBJECT_ID('Table2'))
ORDER BY name
```

Update: Dynamic SQL version (still have to plop table names in manually):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name
                           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name
                                  FROM sys.columns
                                  WHERE object_id IN (OBJECT_ID('Table1'),OBJECT_ID('Table2'))
                                     AND Name <> 'ID'
                                  )sub
                            ORDER BY name
                            FOR XML PATH('')        
                            ), 1, 1, '' ))
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' +@cols+'
            FROM Table1 a
            JOIN Table2 b
              ON a.ID = b.ID
           '
EXEC (@sql)
```